# Django forms: how do is_valid() and validation errors work together?

Tags: python, django

In the below snippet, I'm validating a basic email form. This seems to work just fine (when I type in emails that aren't valid, the correct errors are raised), but I'm a little confused by what's going on behind the scenes.

Walking through the logic here: if the form is valid, then I know what happens.

However, what happens if the form isn't valid? I guess I'm confused, since there is no `else` statement, and so I'm wondering if `is_valid` generates a list of validation errors that are used later in the `return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})`? If not, how exactly are the validation errors generated? I've tried digging through the Django documentation, but I don't see much besides `is_valid` returns a boolean...

Is that what's going on? Could someone help verify, or if I'm off, help explain what happens when the form is *not* valid? Thanks!

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubscriberForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            sub = Subscriber(email=request.POST['email'])
            sub.save()
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'email': sub.email, 'action': 'added'})
    else:
        form = SubscriberForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

In case it's needed for context, an excerpt from my **forms.py**:

```
class SubscriberForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Enter your email:',
                             max_length=100,
                             widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if Subscriber.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return email
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Form instance is either **bound** to a set of data, or **unbound**.

- If it’s bound to a set of data, it’s capable of validating that data
- If it’s unbound, it cannot do validation

```
class Form:
    ...
    def is_valid(self):
        """Return True if the form has no errors, or False otherwise."""
        return self.is_bound and not self.errors
```

With a bound Form instance, call the **`.is_valid()`** method to run validation and return a **boolean** designating whether the form **is bound and the data is valid(has no errors)**

- **`self.is_bound`** check whether the data is passed to form
- **`self.errors`** check the **property error**, which will trigger the full validation process(if `_errors` not populated yet)

```
class Form:
    ...
    @property
    def errors(self):
        """Return an ErrorDict for the data provided for the form."""
        if self._errors is None:
            self.full_clean()
        return self._errors
```

After that, `self.full_clean` will trigger [a series of validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation), including cleaning individual field(`self._clean_fields`), whole form(`self._clean_form`), and post clean hooker(`_self._post_clean`).

In the process, any client side code that raises **`ValidationError`** (i.e `raise ValidationError("Email already exists")`)  will be properly handled by `Form` itself by adding these errors to the **`form._errors`** attribute, which eventually, you could access through **`form.errors`** property

```
class BaseForm:
    ...
    def full_clean(self):
        """
        Clean all of self.data and populate self._errors and self.cleaned_data.
        """
        self._errors = ErrorDict()
        self.cleaned_data = {}
        
        # these three methods will populate the _errors, cleaned_data attribute
        self._clean_fields()
        self._clean_form()
        self._post_clean()

    def _clean_fields(self):
        # simplified for demonstration purpose
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            try:
                validate(field)
            #  your ValidationError("Email already exists") will be catched here
            except ValidationError as e:
                # add errors to `form._error` dict
                self.add_error(name, e)
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful -- much appreciated! This covers all that I was curious about, and then some. Thanks again!